# Tangram self.view downcasting to TGMapView. Where is self.view assigned?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tangram

In Tangram's [current demo app](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram-es/tree/master/platforms/ios/demo), the below method is defined in MapViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TGMapView *mapView = (TGMapView *)self.view;
    mapView.mapViewDelegate = self;
    mapView.gestureDelegate = self;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
}
```

The first thing that happens, after super, is a downcast of the self.view to be of type TGMapView. Two questions that might have the related answers:

1. Generally, where is self.view assigned a value?
2. With what init method is a view or custom view created?

---

After further research, I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview?language=objc) on the apple docs. It seems to imply that custom UIView must have these inits. It isn't clear to me why two different inits would be required, but I can assume that apple uses one or both to initialize the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to specify a view for view controller (More details in "View Management" section of [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller?language=objc)):

- In a storyboard
- In a nib file
- Overriding controller's loadView method and create view there explicitly.

Demo app you've linked to uses storyboards to create UI and custom class for a view is specified in [Main_iPhone.storyboard](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram-es/blob/master/platforms/ios/demo/resources/Main_iPhone.storyboard) (and Main_iPad.storyboard).